# Is GridSearchCV computing SVC with rbf kernel and different degrees?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search

I'm running a `GridSearchCV` with a `OneVsRestClasssifer` using `SVC` as an estimator. This is the aspect of my `Pipeline` and `GridSearchCV` parameters:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(verbose=True), n_jobs=1)),
    ])

parameters = {
    "clf__estimator__C": [0.1, 1],
    "clf__estimator__kernel": ['poly', 'rbf'],
    "clf__estimator__degree": [2, 3],
}

grid_search_tune = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=2, n_jobs=8, verbose=10)
grid_search_tune.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

According to the documentation of SVC the `degree` parameter is only used by the `poly` kernel:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

> degree : int, optional (default=3)
>
> Degree of the polynomial kernel
>   function (‘poly’). Ignored by all other kernels.

but when I see the output of my `GridSearchCV` it seems it's computing a different run for each `SVC` configuration with a `rbf` kernel and different values for the `degree` parameter.

```
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=poly, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=2
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=poly, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=2
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=rbf, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=2
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=rbf, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=2
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=poly, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=3
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=poly, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=3
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=rbf, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=3
[CV] clf__estimator__kernel=rbf, clf__estimator__C=0.1, clf__estimator__degree=3
```

Shouldn't all values of degree be ignored, when the kernel is set to `rbf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output shown here is only the different combinations of parameters passed by the `GridSearchCV` to the internal estimator i.e. the `SVC`. But whether or not they are used depends upon the `SVC`. In this case, the `SVC` doesnt throw any error, but also doesnt use the `degree`. You should print the scores of all those combinations of which you are doubtful. They should be equal. That will tell you that the `degree` parameter is unused.

**Note**: Make sure to set the `random_state` of the `GridSearchCV` to duplicate the tests.

**Explanation**: 
The work of GridSearchCV is to just pass the parameters, the train data to estimator for fitting, then use the test data for scoring, and results the parameter combinations which resulted in best score.

When an incompatible combination of parameter is passed to an estimator, it is dependent on the implementation, whether the parameters are ignored or an error is raised for it.

For eg. in [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), there are two parameters:

> ```
> penalty : str, ‘l1’ or ‘l2’, default: ‘l2’ 
>          Used to specify the norm used in the penalization.
>
> solver : {‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’}, default: ‘liblinear’. 
>          Algorithm to use in the optimization problem.
>         ‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’ and ‘sag’ only handle L2 penalty.
> ```

As you can see, if I use `l1` penalty with `newton-cg` solver, it results in incompatibility. So the estimator may chose to ignore the penalty paramter altogether or throw an error. In this case it throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have to check the scores, but I suspect that for each different degree value, a run of SVC(kernel='rbf') is being compute, which if being true, is a waste time, since all the scores should be the same.

GridSearchCV should be "smart" enough to discard these scores, I will write about it the sklearn mailing-list.

Comment: @DavidBatista Yes. Same run will be computed for different values of degrees. Sure about the mailing-list. We can change the dict to a list of dicts with only compatible combinations together in a dict. Something like `tuned_parameters` in :http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-digits-py